# How to pass a C struct with Java implemented callback to a C function with JNA with generics

Tags: java, c, jna

I am wrapping a C function in Java. This function accepts function pointers to be used in the function body as callbacks.
These callbacks are implemented in Java. Since there are several of them, I grouped them in a C structure which I pass to the wrapped function as an execution context.

When executing this code, I get an exception stack trace

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Structure field "emitDataFn" was declared as interface fr.melchiore.tools.cwrapping.CStructContext$emitData, which is not supported within a Structure
        at com.sun.jna.Structure.writeField(Structure.java:876)
        at com.sun.jna.Structure.write(Structure.java:780)
        at com.sun.jna.Structure.autoWrite(Structure.java:2166)
        at com.sun.jna.Function.convertArgument(Function.java:532)
        at com.sun.jna.Function.invoke(Function.java:345)
        at com.sun.jna.Library$Handler.invoke(Library.java:265)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy16.processElement(Unknown Source)
        at fr.melchiore.tools.cwrapping.CStructWrappedFunction.processElement(CStructWrappedFunction.java:62)
        at fr.melchiore.tools.cwrapping.CStructWrappedFunction.processElement(CStructWrappedFunction.java:12)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.ProcessOperator.processElement(ProcessOperator.java:66)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.io.StreamOneInputProcessor.processElement(StreamOneInputProcessor.java:164)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.io.StreamOneInputProcessor.processInput(StreamOneInputProcessor.java:143)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.performDefaultAction(StreamTask.java:276)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.run(StreamTask.java:298)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.invoke(StreamTask.java:403)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.doRun(Task.java:705)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:530)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No suitable constructor found for class: com.sun.jna.Structure
        at com.sun.jna.Structure.validate(Structure.java:2213)
        at com.sun.jna.CallbackReference.getNativeType(CallbackReference.java:275)
        at com.sun.jna.CallbackReference.<init>(CallbackReference.java:248)
        at com.sun.jna.CallbackReference.getFunctionPointer(CallbackReference.java:449)
        at com.sun.jna.CallbackReference.getFunctionPointer(CallbackReference.java:426)
        at com.sun.jna.Pointer.setValue(Pointer.java:885)
        at com.sun.jna.Structure.writeField(Structure.java:868)
        ... 17 more
```

I know it is possible to implement C callbacks in Java with JNA Callback interface.
From the exception stack trace, it seems storing JNA Callbacks as fields of a JNA Structure and then passing that struct to a JNA libray function is not supported.

Can someone confirm or propose an alternative solution which keeps the context structure ?

**Note that most of these classes are generic.**

Currently, the context structure is defined as follows:

```java
public final class CStructContext<O extends Structure> extends Structure {
    public emitData<O> emitDataFn;
    public emitMC emitMCFn;

    CStructContext() {}

    CStructContext(emitData<O> emitDataFn, emitMC emitMCFn) {
        this();

        this.emitDataFn = emitDataFn;
        this.emitMCFn = emitMCFn;
    }

    @Override
    protected List<String> getFieldOrder() {
        return Arrays.asList("emitDataFn", "emitMCFn");
    }

    interface emitData<O extends Structure> extends Callback {
        void invoke(O data);
    }

    interface emitMC extends Callback {
        void invoke(String event);
    }
}
```

`emitMc` and `emitData` are the two callbacks I want to implement in Java.

The C library is wrapped like this

```java
public interface CStructProcessingLibrary<I extends Structure, O extends Structure> extends Library {

    /* ..SNIPPET.. */

    void processElement(I value, CStructContext<O> ctx);

}
```

The code tying all of these together is:

```java
        CStructProcessingLibrary<I, O> wrapped = Native.load(libName, CStructProcessingLibrary.class);

        final CStructContext<O> cCtx =
                new CStructContext<>();

        cCtx.emitDataFn = new CStructContext.emitData<O>() {
            @Override
            public void invoke(O data) {
                /* ..SNIPPET.. */
            }
        };

        cCtx.emitMCFn = new CStructContext.emitMC() {
            @Override
            public void invoke(String event) {
                /* ..SNIPPET.. */
            }
        };

        wrapped.processElement(value, cCtx);
    }
```

The exception is thrown from the `wrapped.processElement` invocation.